# response elements in transcription regulation

Tags: homework, transcription, gene-regulation, transcription-factor

I'm studying eukaryotic gene regulation and I want to know whether there are some instances where transcription factors don't need to bind to response elements to initiate transcription. RNA polymerase can directly bind to the DNA.
I can't find any evidence for this. Does anyone know of a case that exhibits this?